# Unity 2D enemies not rendering in camera view at x=100+

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I'm working on a 2D Game in Unity and I was designing a level and for some reason , after placing some enemies at around x=145 they just don't show up in the game view even if they should render . I did not change any settings in the Culling Mask of the main camera . Also I'm using Cinemachine for the camera movement.[image: SS of the Scene view and Game view]

I would very much appreciate any help , because I can't really figure out what's the reason

Comment: Is it possible to share Cameras' properties?

Comment: If it's a 2D game, why the Z-axis position of your enemy is not zero? The object might be out of the camera's view when it's like that, unless you accounted for it. Other than that, sharing your camera's properties will help, as this could be related to multiple reasons.

Answer (score 0):

@LeoD You were correct . The actual problem was that the enemies (for some reason) had the z coordinate to -20 or something , my camera having the z coordinate of -10 , so that would place the enemies behind the camera,  not rendering . Thank you very much for your answer , sometimes I just don't see obvious things ;)